# How to specify HTTP error 422 instead of 400 in Hapi Joi

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, joi

Is there a way to get status 422 instead
of 400 in https://github.com/hapijs/joi

### UPDATE

after the reply of @Matt Harrison

to apply the logic globally you can in
your index.js

```
server.ext('onPreResponse', function (request, reply) {
    var req = request.response;
    if (req.isBoom && (req.output.statusCode===400)) {
            return reply(Boom.badData(req.output.payload.message));
    }
        return reply.continue();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joi itself doesn't know or care about HTTP or status codes. It's just for validating JavaScript values.

But I'm guessing you're using Joi with hapi. In this case it's hapi that's giving you a 400. You can override this by using the `failAction` property in the validation [config](http://hapijs.com/api#route-options).

You can also use [Boom](https://github.com/hapijs/boom) to create an HTTP-friendly 422 error.

```
var Boom = require('boom');

server.route({
    config: {
        validate: {
            ...
            failAction: function (request, reply, source, error) {

                reply(Boom.badData('Bad data', error.data));
            }
        }
    },
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: I've updated the question with a possible way to set the logic globally